# C++ template argument using function pointer

Tags: c++, templates

My code as follow:   
I use a function pointer to create a template class object. Why I do this is that my comparator class Less uses a member function to show the result.But if I define a class with operator(), It will make an error that inner class can't visit the outer class's nonstatic member. So I'd use a function to make the template argument.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Comp>
class Compare{
private:
    int a[10]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
public:
//  class Less{ //use inner class, can't visit the member function in OuterClass like java. so we'd use a function pointer to initialize the template
//      public: 
//          
//  };
    bool Less(int v1, int v2){
        return a[v1] < a[v2];
    }
private:
    Comp comp;
public:
    void compare(int v1, int v2){
        cout << comp(v1, v2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Compare<&Compare::Less> c;
    c.compare(1, 2);    
}
```

However, I got errors like follows:

```
In function 'int main()':
[Error] template argument 1 is invalid
[Error] invalid type in declaration before ';' token
[Error] request for member 'compare' in 'c', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

really want to know why. Thx!:)

Comment: Judging by your attempted code, I would say: Take a step back and go through the fundamentals of class templates and function templates in a text book. Getting an answer to this specific problem won't help you in the long run. You need to build your foundation first.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this using a functor is that you want to only overload the operator() and put the array as private member inside the functor and create this functor as an instance in the main to call it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Comparator{
private:
    int a[10]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
public:
    bool operator()(int v1, int v2) const{
        return a[v1] < a[v2];
    }
};


int main(){
    Comparator less;
    cout<<less(1,2)<<endl;
}
```

If you are writing comparator for Dijkstra algorithm, u should define a simple function pointer without the array as private member just overload the operator() instead passing in the array or vector in the min_heap you defined, a similar approach can be found in std::priority_queue

```
    template<class Comparable>
    Comparator<Comparable> comp;
    std::priority_queue<Comparable, vector<Comparable>, Comparator<Comparable>> pq(comp,a);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't the member operator better be `const`?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

```
&Compare::Less
```

Is not a type, whereas template expects a type. It is a value of `bool (Compare::*)(int, int)`. You can safely use `decltype(&Compare::Less)`.

**Design:**

The design seems fragile, so the problem with the template is probably not the right problem to solve.

Also, I second what @R.Sahu said, try to revisit the fundamentals.

For the algorithm implementation I recommend you to draw inspiration from [boost.graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)

Comment: yes. I'm trying to write a dijkstra algorithm. It will use the MinHeap written by my self. The MinHeap is about this:

Comment: @wind2412, even though I've never written it, I'm not sure how the code you've showed has any connection with the algorithm.

Comment: sorry, I did't complete my writting and send it out...yes. I'm trying to write a dijkstra algorithm. It will use the MinHeap written by my self. The MinHeap is about this: MinHeap<typename T, typename Comp>. The 2nd argument is an comparator. But when I write the dijkstra, I should use a member variable like the array on my question...but a comparator couldn't have a member variable.So I can only use a member function to use the array...So It becomes the condition now. But If I want to pass a function pointer to a template argument like my condition, what should I do? thanks!

Comment: @wind2412, modules should be orthogonal. If you have something in common between them then they are not orthogonal. Non orthogonal modules lead to heavier problems in the longer run.